# Rails Sprockets assets. When is it necessary

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, performance, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am wondering what is the best use case for Sprockets on Rails.
From what I understand it is **best** to use it when you have javascript and css resources that are going to be used on all or almost all views. Like jquery.
But as an example if I have a controller for Users, I will have a users.js or users.coffee file. It is included in the application.js file thanks to: 
`//= require_tree .`
But if for my users.js I include 
`//= require chartkick`
 it will include the chartkick dependencies in the application.js, and thus increasing the file size.
**In this case, should I keep users.js separate from the sprockets application.js file?**

Comment: Sprockets is a general assets pipeline. There is nothing that says that you have to concatenate everything into a single file just because you are using Sprockets. Rather what sprockets provides is concatenation, minification and source maps.

Comment: Its not just a question of file size. You also have consider caching after the first page, and limits to the amount of assets a browser can load concurrently. If you want a best practice then its to not require the same thing twice. Either put the dependency it in your manifest or the subfiles - not both.

Comment: that makes sense. Thank for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprockets is just a general assets pipeline. To quote [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max):

> Sprockets is a general assets pipeline. There is nothing that says that you have to concatenate everything into a single file just because you are using Sprockets. Rather what sprockets provides is concatenation, minification and source maps.
>   Its not just a question of file size. You also have consider caching after the first page, and limits to the amount of assets a browser can load concurrently. If you want a best practice then its to not require the same thing twice. Either put the dependency it in your manifest or the subfiles - not both.